# python: gtk FileChooser how to set URI?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am doing some testing with gtk.FileChooser. Specifically I need to pass in a FileChooserDialog and pull a URI or Filename from it. But I want to be able to define the URI so that I know what to check for.

Whenever I define the URI (FileChooserDialog or FileChooserWidget) it doesn't give me back the response using accessors until I interact with the widget or dialog.

Here is a log from my terminal:

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk
>>> import os
>>> 
>>> path = '/home/carlm/workspace/playground'
>>> os.path.exists(path)
True
>>> file_chooser = Gtk.FileChooserDialog('', None, Gtk.FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER)
>>> file_chooser.get_uri()
'file:///home/carlm'
>>> file_chooser.get_filename()
'/home/carlm'
>>> file_chooser.set_uri('file://' + path)
True
>>> file_chooser.get_uri()
>>> file_chooser.run()
-4
>>> file_chooser.get_uri()
'file:///home/carlm/workspace/playground'
>>> file_chooser.get_filename()
'/home/carlm/workspace/playground'
```

During the run I did nothing but click the x button to close the dialog.

Is there anyway to allow me to be able to retrieve the URI or Filename without having to force an interaction in some way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there anyway to allow me to be able to retrieve the URI or Filename without having to force an interaction in some way? From the GTK docs it seems there is not

Comment: What a weird thing that is then. Thanks for that info.